# What does the !! operator mean in R, particularly in the context !!sym("x")

Tags: r, dplyr, operators, rlang

What does "!!" do in R, and why would you use it?

Specifically, I'm looking at a function that involves the phrase
`a = !!sym("x")` where `"x"` is a string. I thought `sym` worked by turning a string into an object, so `a = sym("x")` would set `a` equal to the object `x`. What is the `!!` there for? I read that it unquotes whatever is after it, but I thought `sym` itself unquoted strings?

I also see `!!` used with other functions. What is it doing?

Comment: You can check `help("!!")`

Comment: https://youtu.be/nERXS3ssntw

Answer (score 36):

When you convert a string to a symbol, it prints without the quotes, but that's NOT what unquoting means (we'll get back to that in the end).

`rlang::sym()` is creating a symbol from a string, it's almost the same as `base::as.symbol()` (tiny differences irrelevant to this answer), itself an alias for `base::as.name()` :

```r
nm <- "Sepal.Width"
x <- rlang::sym(nm)
x
#> Sepal.Width
typeof(x)
#> [1] "symbol"
identical(x, as.symbol(nm))
#> [1] TRUE
```

Those don't work, as `x` and `nm` are respectively a symbol and a character, so I can't multiply them by `2`:

```
dplyr::mutate(head(iris),SW2 = nm * 2)
#> Error in nm * 2: argument non numérique pour un opérateur binaire
dplyr::mutate(head(iris),SW2 = x * 2)
#> Error in x * 2: argument non numérique pour un opérateur binaire
```

`!!` doesn't do anything by itself and is not a real operator, it tells `mutate()` to do something though, because `mutate()` is designed to recognize it.

What it tells to `mutate()` is to act as if `!!x` was replaced by the quoted content of x.

```
# equivalent to dplyr::mutate(head(iris), Sepal.Width * 2)
dplyr::mutate(head(iris), !!x * 2)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
#>   Sepal.Width * 2
#> 1             7.0
#> 2             6.0
#> 3             6.4
#> 4             6.2
#> 5             7.2
#> 6             7.8
```

`dplyr::mutate(head(iris), !!sym("Sepal.Width") * 2)` would give the same output.

Why it is called unquoting might be easier to understand by looking at this other equivalent call :

```
quoted <- quote(Sepal.Width * 2)
dplyr::mutate(head(iris), !!quoted)
```

See `help("!!")` for more details.

Comment: What's the difference between !!sym("y") and !!("y")?

Comment: `bang_bang_aware_fun(!!"y")` is the same as `bang_bang_aware_fun("y")`. `bang_bang_aware_fun(!!sym("y"))` is the same as `bang_bang_aware_fun(y)`. if y is the string `"something"`,`bang_bang_aware_fun(!!y)` is the same as `bang_bang_aware_fun("something")`