# Recode different values in multiple columns as factor

Tags: r, tidyverse

assuming I have a data set that looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame("age" = c(55, 21, 11), 
                 "sex" = c("m", "m", "f"),
                 "a2" = c(0,1,0),
                 "a3" = c(0,0,0),
                 "a4" = c(0,1,0),
                 "b2" = c(0,0,1),
                 "b3" = c(0,0,0),
                 "b4" = c(1,0,1),
                 "c2" = c(0,1,0)
                 )
```

```
age sex a2 a3 a4 b2 b3 b4 c2
 55   m  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
 21   m  1  0  1  0  0  0  1
 11   f  0  0  0  1  0  1  0
```

How would I be able to transform it into long format and change the values of columns a1-c1 so that every column has the value of its name? e. g. in a2 0=1 and 1=2?

I tried it with pivot_longer like this:

```
df %>% pivot_longer(
   cols = stars_with("a"),
   names_to = "A"
)
```

My desired output looks like this:

```
age sex a2 a3 a4 b2 b3 b4 c2
 55   m  1  1  1  1  1  4  1
 21   m  2  1  4  1  3  1  2
 11   f  1  1  1  2  1  4  1
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not clear what your desired output is. a3=0 becomes 1 or ?? And 1 becomes 2 or ??3.  You ask for longer a* to c* but are only using starts with a? Can you post a reproducable example i.e. the code to make df (see dput) and what you are hoping to see?

Comment: @CALUMPolwart Hi! I edited my post. Basically I want the number in the column name as the value for 1.  I dont use a-c because in the data set they are not in that order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good question because you cannot access column names within `mutate_at`, which is how you would normally mutate across a list of variables. Here is a solution using `map_dfc` from `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
```

We define a function (although not necessary but helpful to avoid foreign syntax if you are not accustomed to `purrr`.

```
my_fun <- function(x) transmute(df, !!x := ifelse(!!sym(x) == 0, 1, parse_number(x)))
```

`transmute` to avoid duplicate columns

`!!x :=` is a way to assign a column name based on a string from a variable. In our case, a column name.

`!!sym()` converts our variable name from a string to a symbol. Without this, for column 'a2' this would read `"a2" == 0` thus replacing with the column number. [Refer to this answer for an in-depth explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57417926/7153771)

`parse_number` will find the number within the column name

`ifelse` states if the column value is equal to 0, then the value equals 1, otherwise the value is equal to the number in the column name

```
var_names <- c("a2","a3","a4","b2","b3","b4","c2")

map_dfc(var_names, my_fun)
```

Comment: Can you please add a brief blurb about what `sym()` is doing here?

Comment: @iamericfletcher I have edited the explanation in.

Answer (score 4):

`pivot_longer` is not appropriate strategy here.  Follow `mutate` with across.

- `across` will pass desired columns into mutate statement
- `cur_column()` will pass current colnames into syntax

```
library(dplyr)
library (stringr) 
df %>% mutate(across(-c("age", "sex"), ~ ifelse(. == 0, 1, as.numeric(str_extract(cur_column(), "\\d$")))))

  age sex a2 a3 a4 b2 b3 b4 c2
1  55   m  1  1  1  1  1  4  1
2  21   m  2  1  4  1  1  1  2
3  11   f  1  1  1  2  1  4  1
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R you could do:

```r
# extract numbers from column names
vals <- as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]+", "", colnames(df)[-c(1:2)]))

# replace 0 with 1 and 1 with extracted number in each column
df[, -c(1:2)] <- sapply(seq_along(vals), function(x) ifelse(df[, x+2]==0, 1, vals[x]))
```

Comment: similar `df[, -c(1:2)] <- Map('^', vals, df[, -c(1:2)])`

Answer (score 2):

Base R option using `Map` :

```
inds <- -(1:2)
cols <- as.integer(sub('[a-z](\\d+)', '\\1', names(df)[inds]))
df[inds] <- Map(function(x, y) ifelse(x == 1, y, 1), df[inds], cols)
df

#  age sex a2 a3 a4 b2 b3 b4 c2
#1  55   m  1  1  1  1  1  4  1
#2  21   m  2  1  4  1  1  1  2
#3  11   f  1  1  1  2  1  4  1
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility (though may not be the most efficient)

```
library(tidyverse)
as_tibble(df) %>% transmute(
  a2 = case_when(a2 == 1 ~ 2, a2 == 0 ~ 1),
  a3 = case_when(a3 == 1 ~ 3, a3 == 0 ~ 1),
  a4 = case_when(a4 == 1 ~ 4, a4 == 0 ~ 1),
  b2 = case_when(b2 == 1 ~ 2, b2 == 0 ~ 1),
  b3 = case_when(b3 == 1 ~ 3, b3 == 0 ~ 1),
  b4 = case_when(b4 == 1 ~ 4, b4 == 0 ~ 1),
  c2 = case_when(c2 == 1 ~ 2, c2 == 0 ~ 1)
)
```

If you wish to keep the other columns use `mutate()` instead of `transmute()`.